# Running Postman collections in CLI newman error - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND {{base_url}}

Tags: postman, newman

I have written test cases for API collections in postman and trying to run those through Newman plug-in in my local machine. I have downloaded the JSON file in documents on my mac

I am using this command to run : newman run QA_api_testing.postman_collection.json

getting below error with all the api’s failing
error message: GET {{base_url}}/companies/active/all [errored]
** getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND {{base_url}}**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHj2W.png)
pls help me

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a variable `base_url`, and newman doesn't know it.

Define `base_url` as an environment variable, export it, and pass the file as a parameter to newman.

Alternatively, you could simply add that one value to your newman call, by adding: `--env-var base_url=https://YourUrl`